# i am inserting the data but when get the data always give me null @capacitor-community/sqlite

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic7

public async insertData(data: any) {
const insertDataQuery = `INSERT INTO farm_add ( officer_name, resolved_by, resolved_date, resolved_details, resolved_yn, visit_date, visit_purpose, visit_type ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;

```
try {
  const values:any = [
    data.officer_name,
    data.resolved_by,
    data.resolved_date,
    data.resolved_details,
    data.resolved_yn ? 1 : 0,
    data.visit_date,
    data.visit_purpose,
    data.visit_type
  ];

  const result = await this.db.execute(insertDataQuery, values);
  console.log('Insert result:', result);

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error inserting data:', error);
}
```

}

public async getAllData() {
const getAllDataQuery = 'SELECT * FROM farm_add';

```
  try {
    const result = await this.db.query(getAllDataQuery, []);
    
    if (result.values && result.values.length > 0) {
      const data = result.values;
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } else {
      console.error('Error retrieving data:', result);
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing query:', error);
    return [];
  }
}
```

i want to get he data but got null values

id
:
2
officer_name
:
null
resolved_by
:
null
resolved_date
:
null
resolved_details
:
null
resolved_yn
:
null
visit_date
:
null
visit_purpose
:
null
visit_type
:
null

inserting like this
const yourData = {
officer_name: "Ashwin",
resolved_by: "yes",
resolved_date: "2023-06-20",
resolved_details: "Germination percentage was 90%.",
resolved_yn: 1,
visit_date: "2020-06-20",
visit_purpose: "monitoring of rice planting.",
visit_type: null,
};

```
  this.datasService.insertData(yourData)
```